# Ruby: Script won't grab URL from youtube correctly

Tags: ruby, youtube, bots

I found this script on pastebin that is an IRC bot that will find youtube videos for you. I have not touched it at all (Bar the channel settings), it works well however it won't grab the URL to the video that has been searched. This code is not mine! I jsut would like to get it to work as it would be quite useful!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'cinch'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'cgi'

bot = Cinch::Bot.new do
  configure do |c|
    c.server = "irc.freenode.net"
    c.nick = "YouTubeBot"
    c.channels = ["#test"]
  end

  helpers do

    #Grabs the first result and returns the TITLE,LINK,DESCRIPTION

    def youtube(query)

      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.youtube.com/results?q=#{CGI.escape(query)}"))

      result = doc.css('div#search-results div.result-item-main-content')[0]

      title = result.at('h3').text
      link = "www.youtube.com"+"#{result.at('a')[:href]}"
      desc = result.at('p.description').text

    rescue
        "No results found"
    else
      CGI.unescape_html "#{title} - #{desc} - #{link}"

    end
  end

  on :channel, /^!youtube (.+)/ do |m, query|
      m.reply youtube(query)
  end

  on :channel, "polkabot quit" do |m|
    m.channel.part("bye")
  end
end

bot.start
```

Currently if i use the command

!youtube asdf

I get this returned:

> 19:25 < YouTubeBot> asdfmovie - Worldwide Store www.cafepress.com ...
>   asdfmovie cakebomb tomska 
>                       epikkufeiru asdf movie ... tomska ... [Baby Giggling] Man: Got your nose! [Baby ... 
>                       - www.youtube.com#

As you can see the URL is just www.youtube.com# not the URL of the video.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an xpath issue. It looks like the third 'a' that has the href you want so try:

```
link = "www.youtube.com#{result.css('a')[2][:href]}"
```